# How do I ask a set of questions multiple times based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Using Python 3.7. I'm attempting to gather information based on the dimensions of objects but I'm having trouble figuring out the right syntax.

The goal is to ask how many objects there are and what each object's lengths and widths are. Here's what I have so far:

```
num_of_objects = int(input("Enter the number of objects:"))
a = 1

while a <= num_of_objects:
    length = input("Enter length of object:")
    width = input("Enter width of object:")
```

As of right now, it outputs this on what seems to be an infinite loop despite `num_of_objects` input:

```
Enter the number of objects: 4 
Enter length of object: 
Enter width of object:
```

What I'd like it to ask is something along the lines of:

```
Enter the number of objects: 4 
Enter length of object 1: 
Enter width of object 1:
Enter length of object 2:
Enter width of object 2:
Enter length of object 3:
Enter width of object 3:
Enter length of object 4:
Enter width of object 4:
```

I've tried a number of things but to no avail.

Comment: of course it's an infinite loop - a is not changed  within the loop so it's 1 forever... If you already know that you want to loop `a` times, just use `for i in range(a):`. Then you automatically end after `a` sets of questions and additionally you can use `i+1` for your object counter in the questions.

Comment: You need one final statement in your loop: `a += 1`.  Better yet, replace the `while` with a `for` loop.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Start with simple `print` statements to trace logic and data flow.  In this case, you would trace the loop with `print a, length, width`.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python loops", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

**Start by writing logic, not code**. When your logic makes sense, then you get to turn your logic into code.

So how do you write logic? You need an *algorithm*:

> In mathematics and computer science, an algorithm is an unambiguous specification of how to solve a class of problems

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm

So let's write an algorithm to describe the program you want to write:

1. Ask the user for a number of objects, and save the result as `num_objects`
2. For every object, ask the user for the object's length and width

Not so bad, right? Let's write some code!

"But wait," you might ask -- "where do I start?"

Great question. Let's start by laying out the structure of the program we would like:

```
def main():
    num_objects = ask_num_objects()
    object_sizes = ask_object_sizes(num_objects)
```

OK, that seems like a minimal but reasonable implementation of our algorithm.

Let's implement `ask_num_objects`:

```
def ask_num_objects():
    return int(input("Enter the number of objects:"))
```

That was easy. You already wrote that code, I just copied it from your question text.

Next, we need to implement `ask_object_sizes`. This is where you had a logic error in your code. As the commenters pointed out, you didn't write the loop properly:

```
def ask_object_sizes(num_objects):
    sizes = []
    for i in range(num_objects)
        length = input("Enter length of object {}:".format(i))
        width = input("Enter width of object {}:".format(i))

        sizes.append((length, width))

    return sizes
```

Take a moment to make sure you understand what this code does, and why it's different from your existing code!

We can put this all together as follows:

```
def ask_num_objects():
    return int(input("Enter the number of objects:"))

def ask_object_sizes(num_objects):
    sizes = []
    for i in range(num_objects)
        length = input("Enter length of object {}:".format(i))
        width = input("Enter width of object {}:".format(i))

        sizes.append((length, width))

    return sizes

def main():
    num_objects = ask_num_objects()
    object_sizes = ask_object_sizes(num_objects)

    # do something with object_sizes
```

Answer (score 0):

As many comments have pointed out: you're looping until `a` exceeds `num_of_objects`, but you're never incrementing `a` inside the loop.

A common idiom to avoid this is:

```
for _ in range(num_of_objects):
    # do some stuff
```

`range(x)` (where `x` is an integer) creates a generator that produces the set of numbers `[0,x)`, which has length `x`. The `_` in `for _ in ...` just means we're ignoring the loop index (because you're not using it now, either.

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value of `a` you could fix this by simply increasing its value after ever loop like so

```
while a <= num_of_objects:
    length = input("Enter length of object:")
    width = input("Enter width of object:")
    a += 1
```

> ```
> Enter the number of objects:4
> Enter length of object:1
> Enter width of object:2
> Enter length of object:1
> Enter width of object:2
> Enter length of object:1
> Enter width of object:2
> Enter length of object:1
> Enter width of object:2
> ```

Even so we should avoid `while` loops and use a `for` loop like this

```
for i in range(num_of_objects):
    length = input("Enter length of object:")
    width = input("Enter width of object:")
```